# How to get a range of DateTime-Elements in LinkedList between the given start and end datetime

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm getting the data from a server and buffering them in `linked list`. After receiving the data I assign it to a local `timestamp`, so that every element in my `LinkedList` has a `timestamp` attribute. I want now to read out the data for a certain period of time from the buffer.

For example all elements for 1 minute from 28.01.2016 08:44:00 to 28.01.2016 08:45:00.

How could I do it? I would be very grateful for an advice or a sample of code.

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with just walking down the list, starting from the beginning, until you hit the start time, then reading data until you hit the end time?  This should work, assuming that you insert your timestamps in chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

**JAVA 8:**

```
public class TimeInListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        List<Element> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(new Element(dateFormat.parse("28.01.2016 08:43:00 ")));
        list.add(new Element(dateFormat.parse("28.01.2016 08:43:05 ")));
        list.add(new Element(dateFormat.parse("28.01.2016 08:44:00 ")));
        list.add(new Element(dateFormat.parse("28.01.2016 08:44:30 ")));
        list.add(new Element(dateFormat.parse("28.01.2016 08:44:35 ")));
        list.add(new Element(dateFormat.parse("28.01.2016 08:44:38 ")));
        list.add(new Element(dateFormat.parse("28.01.2016 08:45:00 ")));
        list.add(new Element(dateFormat.parse("28.01.2016 08:46:00 ")));

        Date leftLimit = dateFormat.parse("28.01.2016 08:44:00");
        Date rightLimit = dateFormat.parse("28.01.2016 08:45:00");

        System.out.println(list.stream().filter(element -> element.date.after(leftLimit) && element.date.before(rightLimit)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    static class Element {
        Date date;
        String someData;

        public Element() {
        }

        public Element(Date date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        public Date getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(Date date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Element{" +
                    "date=" + date +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

**JAVA 7 (replace lambda):**

```
List<Element> resultList = new LinkedList<>();

        for (Element element: list) {
            if (element.date.after(leftLimit) && element.date.before(rightLimit)) {
                resultList.add(element);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(resultList);
```

Result:

> [Element{date=Thu Jan 28 08:44:30 MSK 2016}, Element{date=Thu Jan 28
>   08:44:35 MSK 2016}, Element{date=Thu Jan 28 08:44:38 MSK 2016}]

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 implementation:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class T35055579 {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, LocalDateTime>> data = new LinkedList<>();
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-01-28T08:43:50", DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            data.add(wrap(String.valueOf(i), start.plusSeconds(i * 11)));
        }
        System.out.println("Full list:");
        print(data);
        String from = "2016-01-28T08:44:00";
        String to = "2016-01-28T08:45:00";
        System.out.println(String.format("Values between [%s, %s]:", from, to));
        print(filter(data, from, to));
    }

    private static List<Map.Entry<String, LocalDateTime>> filter(LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, LocalDateTime>> data, String fromRaw, String toRaw) {
        LocalDateTime from = LocalDateTime.parse(fromRaw, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        LocalDateTime to = LocalDateTime.parse(toRaw, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        return data.stream()
                .filter(d -> between(d.getValue(), from, to))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static boolean between(LocalDateTime value, LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to) {
        return (value.isAfter(from) || value.isEqual(from)) &&
               (value.isBefore(to) || value.isEqual(to));
    }


    private static void print(List<Map.Entry<String, LocalDateTime>> data) {
        data.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Map.Entry<String, LocalDateTime> wrap(String value, LocalDateTime time) {
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(value, time);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Full list:
0=2016-01-28T08:43:50
1=2016-01-28T08:44:01
2=2016-01-28T08:44:12
3=2016-01-28T08:44:23
4=2016-01-28T08:44:34
5=2016-01-28T08:44:45
6=2016-01-28T08:44:56
7=2016-01-28T08:45:07
8=2016-01-28T08:45:18
9=2016-01-28T08:45:29

Values between [2016-01-28T08:44:00, 2016-01-28T08:45:00]:
1=2016-01-28T08:44:01
2=2016-01-28T08:44:12
3=2016-01-28T08:44:23
4=2016-01-28T08:44:34
5=2016-01-28T08:44:45
6=2016-01-28T08:44:56
```